# super glue / adhesive for plastic that is resilient to extreme temperature variation

Tags: adhesive

My car’s side window broke off. The contact surfaces are both plastic.

I managed to glue it back with “Loctite Super Glue Easy Squeeze Gel”. But the result is limited by season. If I glue it on in summer, then it comes off during winter (we regularly have 0 degrees F here). And vice versa.

I'm requesting your recommendations for "plastic on plastic" super glue / adhesive, that can withstand a temperature range of -10F to 110F, and can support a car side window that weighs about two pounds.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happen, and I was able to take out the screws from the inside of the car so the whole broken assembly could be taken inside.

Even though product recommendations are off topic, you should be able to find a good plastic adhesive at any hardware store.

You’d be best off with your adhesive results if you can add a bolt between the two pieces to keep them from moving or flexing the adhesive too much. If you remove the pieces from the car you can probably hide the fastener completely (it depends on how it broke). Clamp the two pieces together and give them plenty of time to cure (check the adhesive on the cure time) before putting it back on your car and into the elements.

Comment: Recommended to me was jb weld plastic cement. http://www.google.com/shopping/product/7781151979588946495?lsf=seller:6169538,store:5369097276248960265,lsfqd:0&prds=oid:16465546918781204162&q=Hardware+Glue+%26+Adhesives&hl=en&ei=aTZjXLu7IPCkggfp7oQQ&lsft=gclid:EAIaIQobChMI5siU6I234AIVKrCzCh21qwt0EAQYASABEgJo9_D_BwE,gclsrc:aw.ds   I just don't know if it has been rated for cold weather.